# Same file in extra tab in Visual Studio 2015 debugger

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

While I'm debugging a page with a break point in our ASP.NET web site in Visual Studio 2015, an extra tab is opened for the same file once the break point is reached:

[image]

[image]

After I stop debugging, the tab remains open and has focus... at which point I begin to make changes to fix something, etc.  However, this tab stops showing Intellisense, nags with a dialog about unsaved changes inside this editor and has been changed externally, etc.

After some checking, it turns out the extra tab that gets opened during debugging (blue tab) is the local file from my local version of the website, while the original tab (brown tab) is my file from my local TFS development directory.

This extra tab is fairly annoying to my workflow and I'd rather it didn't show up, or at least that it disappeared after debugging so that I could continue programming happily.  However, despite my best Google-Fu and looking through the options in Visual Studio, I cannot find a way to either disable this feature or hide this tab after debugging... maybe there isn't a way.

Anyone have the same issue and know a solution?  A grateful programmer would thank you if you do. :)  Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that you use the TFS as the version control tool?Close all project files, just open your local web site again without connect to the TFS, and then just open the project vb file from the solution explorer window, how about the result if you debug it with breakpoint?

Comment: How about the result if you close all vb files and then just open the file in the solution explorer window directly? Would you please share the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT - Apologies for the delay in responding, it's been busy the last several days.  I updated the pics in the original post to (hopefully) explain more clearly what I'm seeing.  I tried both of your suggestions above but got the same results.  I don't recall this happening before VS 2015... I was going to reinstall VS 2013 and possibly earlier versions to see if I still get the same results.  Another clarifying point - this is an old Web Site project and not a Web Application project if that makes a difference.

Comment: How about the result if you use the VS2013? If you just create a blank solution, and then add all project files to this new blank solution, clean and rebuild your project, debug it again, how about the result?